# How to change own defined attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering how to change own defined attributes in html tags using JavaScript/jQuery.
For example:
I have defined attributed called ascending:

```
<th ascending="true" id="1">some text</th>
```

and in JavaScript/jQuery I want to change that attribute on "false"
I was trying that way, but it doesn't work(I guess this option is only for predefined attributes):

```
var tag = document.getElementById("1");
    tag.ascending = "false";
```

Comment: if you're using jquery, you may want to consider using the data attribute instead of defining custom ones: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: You shouldn't use your own made up attributes. Looks into the data attribute instead.

Comment: with `tag.ascending`, `ascending` is a property. know the difference between properties and attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom `data-*` attributes when adding customization, else it wont pass validation! In your case:

```
<th data-ascending="true" id="1">some text</th>
```

And to get/set (pure JS):

```
var tag = document.getElementById("1");
tag.getAttribute("data-ascending"); //get
tag.setAttribute("data-ascending", true); //set
```

jQuery:

```
$("#1").data("ascending"); //get
$("#1").data("ascending", true); //set
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "setAttribute" method.

Like this : tag.setAttribute("Ascending","false");

Answer (score 0):

Try this in jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('#1').attr('ascending',false);
});
```

but you should use .prop()

```
$(function(){
  $('#1').prop('ascending',false);
})
```

Or in javascript

```
function changeValue() {
  var tag = getElemendById('1');
  tag.setAttribute('ascending', false);
}
```

and html for javascript version should look like this:

```
<th onLoad="changeValue()" data-ascending="true" id="1">some text</th>
```

I didn't test it but it should work ;)